# Une chose laisse « de neige » ?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques, locutions

Dans *Cyrano de Bergerac* (Rostand), [acte III](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Cyrano_de_Bergerac_(Rostand)/Acte_III), scène II, on trouve :

> *De guiche* : Je viens prendre congé.
> *Roxane* : Vous partez ?
> *De guiche* : Pour la guerre.
> *Roxane* : Ah !
> *De guiche* : Ce soir même.
> *Roxane* : Ah !
> *De guiche* : J’ai des ordres. On assiège Arras.
> *Roxane* : Ah !… on assiège ?… 
>  *De guiche* : Oui… Mon départ a l’air
> de vous laisser **de neige**.
> *Roxane*, poliment : Oh !…

Je comprends la locution *(laisser) de neige* comme l'équivalent de *de [glace](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/glace)*, « sans chaleur, sans effusion, raide, insensible » (TLFi).

- Est-ce bien le cas ou autrement de quel sens s'agit-il ?
- Est-ce bien une locution qui existe ou a déjà existé, puis aurait été remplacée par *de glace*, ou est-ce simplement pour la rime (*assiège/neige*) ?

Answer (score 3):

Oui, la rime est sûrement la motivation première et le sens est forcément *laisser de glace*, *laisser de marbre*.

On trouve extrêmement peu d'autres occurrences, on est très proche du hapax, la neige n'ayant pas tellement des caractéristiques du marbre ou de la glace alors qu'on peut trouver par exemple *laisser de pierre*, et même *laisser de bronze* ou *laisser d'acier*.

Comment: Je suggérerais plutôt une variation de *laisser froid*, la neige partageant cette autre caractéristique de la glace.